# How to debug leaking connections in an ASP.NET 2.0 Web Services application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, .net-2.0, connection-leaks

I have an app, which is a bunch of c# web services sitting on top of ASP.NET 2.0 in IIS7 on Win2k3.  Following the last release, we keep getting connection timeouts. A quick investigation using Perfmon confirmed that our application is leaking connections.

However, there have been so many code changes in the last release, that it is really difficult to determine where the problem is just by looking at code changes.

Is there a way to debug where the connection leaks are actually occurring?

Comment: Problem solved.  SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection) does not actually close the connection, the SqlDataReader still needs to be properly disposed.

Comment: since you have identified that as the issue, also consider using the using statement.  The using statement expands to a try-finally control structure and ensures that the item declared within the parenthesis is properly disposed.  You may already know that, but I thought I'd post this information for any new developers that haven't encountered the 'using' keyword yet.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.  Wasn't my code, I always use "using". Was just troubleshooting it, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use performance counters to check the memory leaks.

See this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx

It can say whether your application is having memory leaks or not? But it will not find
the code which is causing that things. For that you have to debug the application.